# Filter error bag for only visible elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

im trying to validate my form, and for that I need to use errorBag because I have some elements that don't use rules... So when i run the form validation it doesn't catch them.

Example of element:

```
<v-text-field
  v-model.number="dataObject.mydate.year"
  placeholder="Year"
  required
  type="number"
  min="1"
  aria-label="Year:"
  id="year"
  :rules="defaultValidations.yearRules"
  :error="validateDate(dataObject.mydate).estate"
  :error-messages="validateFechaFinDescanso(dataObject.mydate).errorName"
  v-on:keypress="defaultValidations.methods.isNum($event)"
  v-bind="attrs"
></v-text-field>
```

I use this line to catch errors:

```
valid = Object.values(this.$refs.form.errorBag).every(e => !e)
```

The problem is that it always takes errors of elements that are not visible (v-if doesn't show them)

Does anyone know how to fix this line to filter only visible ones?

Thank you

Comment: can you post more details about  your data structure?

Comment: just updated the data